# iOS: optional code fragments for debug builds

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, release, building

for my App I'd like to have a debug view that I want to have only in debug-builds and not in
release builds. I don't want to change my code though. Thats why i am wondering if I can
check some compiler flag if this is a release build and exclude some code that i only want to
have for debug builds.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your projects build settings, look for the preprocessor defines section, in there you can define a variable in your debug build only, such as `DEBUG=1`, and then use this in your code:

```
#if DEBUG
    NSLog(@"This will only print in debug!");
#endif
```

Just make sure in your release configuration, that same define is set to 0 in the same location in your build settings

Comment: #ifdef is another option, but i prefer to use #if instead

Comment: As I said in my comment before, I prefer to use `#if` rather than `#ifdef`.  It is entirely up to the programmer which to use, and each has their advantages and disadvantages.  My preference is to use the method where each flag is always defined, but as a 0 or a 1 to indicate the status of that flag, rather than trying to figure out if that flag is defined at all in the project

Comment: #ifdef will be considered true, even if DEBUG=0 is set in the preprocessor, for that reason I consider it to be dangerous to use #ifdef

Answer (score 29):

Check your projects build settings for debug to ensure that 'DEBUG' is being set - Apple gives you this for free - do this by selecting the project and clicking on the build settings tab. Search for 'DEBUG' and look to see if indeed DEBUG is being set.

[image: Build Settings tab of my project settings]

then conditionally code for DEBUG in your source files

```
#ifdef DEBUG

// Something to log your data here or even add a whole subview to see it on the device

#else

// 

#endif
```

Comment: but what if you submit the app to apple and you forget to set to DEBUG = 0

Comment: Not a problem because, as you can see in the screenshot above, in the **Release** Build Configuration, there is no definition for DEBUG; that is, there is no *DEBUG=1*, as there is for the **Debug** and *TestFlight** Build Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the build setting explained by Damo, there is an equivalent Build Setting which I have seen used and also works.  In *Other C Flags* (OTHER_CFLAGS), add `-DDEBUG` to the *Debug* configuration.