# Conditional Compilation for Different Configurations

Tags: ios, configuration, conditional-compilation

I have a project for which I added a configuration "AppStore" in addition to the default "Debug" and "Release". I want to include a small piece of conditional code based on compiling for the "AppStore" config. How do I do that? Is there a flag associated with that config that is available for an #ifdef? Can I associate a flag myself to tag this config? Should I create another target instead?

Comment: You don't need to create another target. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081334/ios-optional-code-fragments-for-debug-builds

Comment: Ah, thanks, I had not found this. It does answer my question indeed.

Comment: And by the way the answer is: look for the "preprocessor" build settings. Debug already had DEBUG= 1 as you'd expect. I added APPSTORE= 1 for the AppStore configuration, so I can compile optional code after an #ifdef APPSTORE directive.